# Potential energy and force

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, conservative-field

Why force is **negative** gradient of potential energy?
Why negative sign is involved in this definition?

Comment: Think of forces that are associated with potential energies. Gravity e.g. attracts objects, but gravitational potential energy increases with *larger* distance - so gravity pulls in a way such that the potential energy reduces. Or think of elastic forces - the always pull in a way so that the spring returns to relaxed state - meaning, they always pull in a way so that the stored elastic potential energy reduces towards zero.

Answer (score 6):

Your question admits two different answers:

The first, more rigorous kind of answer, is that this simply follows *from the definition* of the potential energy: potential energy is defined such as the inverse (additive inverse to be precise) of its gradient corresponds to the force. That's it, this is what potential energy *means*.

The second, more colloquial kind of answer, involves the interpretation of these quantities: potential energy represents, roughly, how much energy the body has; now: one fundamental tendency of nature is to prefer states with less energy, so makes intuitive sense that the force should point in the direction of "fastest reduction" of potential energy, and this is exactly the direction at which the negative gradient points!

Comment: "*the force should point in the direction of "fastest reduction" of potential energy*" This is the key point. Very well put. +1.

Comment: "one fundamental tendency of nature is to prefer states with less energy" 1.) energy is conserved 2.) if you mean less potential energy, then its circular logic, since we can change the sign and say fundamental tendency is to prefer states with more energy. The same thing with your fastest reduction.

Comment: I think there are two main points. One is our historical experience with gravitational field. We are used to things falling down and getting energy from these falling bodies. And of course, the higher the body starts to fall from, the more (kinetic) energy will it have upon arrival to the ground, thus we want higher altitude bodies to have  bigger potential ( for gaining kinetic energy). Another is conservation of energy. We want it to add to the kinetic energy to get overall energy, not subtract, so that the expression "having a potential energy" actually makes sense.

Comment: @Umaxo We define potential energy to match and fulfill the energy conservation law with other already defined energy quantites such as kinetic energy. We cannot simply change the signs.